# Should I scale values before using them to train autoencoder?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, activation-function

I have a dataset that contains vectors of shape 1xN where N is the number of features. For each value, there is a float between -4 and 5. For my project I need to make an autoencoder, however, activation functions like ReLU or tanh will either only allow positive values through the layers or within -1 and 1. My concern is that upon decoding from the latent space the data will not be represented in the same way, I will either get vectors with positive values only or constrained negative values while I want it to be close to the original.

Should I apply some kind of transformation like adding a positive constant value, exp() or raise data to power 2, train VAE, and then if I want original representation I just log() or log2() the output? Or am I missing some configuration with activation functions that can give me an output similar to the original input?

Comment: But why do you care about the scale of the data in the latent space? That said, normalising the data at [01,] for example, will allow you to have a sigmoid function at your output layer and "simplify" your life, seems to like a simple min-max normalisation step in your preprocessing is needed and you are good to roll. Obviously, if you want a constrained function use a linear activation. Note that while a ReLU for example cannot output cannot be negative, its  output times a weight (which can be negative) can give us negative outputs.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify, I care about the original format of data, my concern is the min-max constrains data to [0,1] range so which changes the underlying relationship between data. When I get my output out of VAE I want it to be in its original format, i.e have negative values, this is important for my project. I used PCA to check before and after I added a constant positive value to make my data not negative, it returned the same plot, but I want to make sure this is an appropriate transformation. Goal is after VAE trains I will just subtract the value to get the original representation.

Comment: But you can undo the minimax... So let's say from what you describe if you do $\frac{x + 4}{9}$ should transform/"whiten" your data for your VAE (that's preprocessing) and then going ahead and doing $(x*9)-4$ should untransform/"colourise" them back (that's post-processing).